# How do I find a solution to this this finite series? $ \frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left({i^3}\right) $

Tags: summation

How do I find a solution to this this finite series? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$$
\frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left({i^3}\right)
$$

Comment: Just check out or google the formula on how to add cubes of consecutive integers and you are through.

Comment: thank you didn't quite know how to phrase it in google

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I gave a derivation of the formulas others have quoted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194072/where-do-summation-formulas-come-from/1194116#1194116

Comment: Well, TIL of the "trivial answer converted to comment" function. I'm not sure I like it in this case...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

You may want to know [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: And then dividing by $n^4$ turns the $n^2$ into $n^{-2}$

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested by the limit, we can also use Riemann sums:
$$\frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac i n\right)^3  \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^1x^3dx=\frac{1}{4}$$

This method can be generalized for higher powers.