# Proving that $P_{k+1}(x) = 1 + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j}P_j (x-1)$

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm struggling a little bit with this proof from Smoryński's *Logical Number Theory*. He has already proven that, if $n \geq 0$, then there's a polynomial $P_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^x k^n$. The idea now is to give a more precise determination of this polynomial, so he, in order to do so, he first proves the lemma in the title of the question. However, I didn't quite get two steps in the proof. I'll reproduce the proof here with my comments, hoping that you folks can help me sort it out.

> $P_{k+1}(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^x i^{k+1}$

By the previously proved theorem;

> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^x i^{k+1} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1} (i+1)^{k+1}$

Using the equation $\sum\limits_{n=s}^t f(n) = \sum\limits_{n=s+p}^{t+p} f(n-p)$;

> $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1} (i+1)^{k+1} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j}i^j$

Using the binomial theorem;

> $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j}i^j = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1}i^j$

Driving the factor $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j}$ out;

> $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1}i^j = x + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j} P_j(x-1)$

Okay, here my doubts begin. It's clear that he used the identity $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1}i^j = P_j(x-1)$ to get to this line (though I'm a bit worried about that index; shouldn't he have adjusted the index to $i=1$ before substituting?), but I don't quite understand where that $x$ came from. I suppose it came from taking the factor $\binom{k+1}{0}i$ out from the sum, but then shouldn't it be $x^{k+1}?$

> $x + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j} P_j(x-1) = 1 + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j} P_j(x-1)$

Now I'm really lost. Where did that $1$ come from? I suppose it's related to the change in the sum, but I can't quite understand which operation he carried out to get $1$.

That's it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Winther Sorry, it's my typo! I'll edit it in a second.

Comment: The $x$ comes from the $j=0$ term ${k+1\choose 0}\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}i^0 = 1\cdot (1 + 1 + \ldots + 1) = x$. For your second questions: The $i=0$ term is zero so we can switch the summation to $i=1$ without any problems.

Comment: @Winther - Alright, that $x$ now makes sense. I was thinking $\binom{k+1}{0}$ multiplied $i$ directly, but now I see that it multiplies that sum. That also explains how he can change the index: if we take out $\binom{k+1}{0}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{x-1} i^0$, this leaves us with $i=1$ inside the summation, right? But I don't get it how he changes $x$ to $1$ in the last equation.

Comment: A different presentation, which presumably leads to the same final conclusion: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1194116/83396

Comment: @Ian - Yes, I checked that link from my last question. It's very useful! However, I had specific questions about this proof, which is why I decided to post a new question.

Comment: If you take out the $j=0$ term that leaves you with $\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{x-1}$ which equals $\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^{x-1} + \sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\text{(summand for $i=0$)}$  where the last term is $0$ since $0^j = 0$ for $j>0$.