# Is there a programmatic way to calculate cascaded sigma functions?

Tags: measure-theory

Let my format be

```
sigma(function,from,to) = f(n)
```

for example

```
sigma(sigma(1 , j = 1 , j = i) , i = 1 , i = n) = (n^2)/2
```

Could someone tell me an algorithmic approach to calculate functions like these? I am making a c++ program which needs this routine. It needs to output a string like `(n^2)/2` or a polynomial vector would be fine too.

It can be more complicated like

```
sigma(sigma(sigma(1, k = 1, k = i + j), j = 1, j = i),i = 1,i = n) = (n^3)/2
```

I found that multi-variable indefinite integration is a good approximation for this. Say for the second example.

```
integrate(integrate(integrate(1,0,i+j,dk),0,i,dj),0,n,di) = (n^3)/2
```

However it seems too much work to make a indefinite integration engine just for this. Any simpler methods will be much appreciated.

Comment: Cf. my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194072/where-do-summation-formulas-come-from You should be able to iterate this to deal with your slightly more complicated summations.

Comment: I was trying to get a general expression.

Comment: By the way, your first example is incorrect; $\sum_{j=0}^i 1 = (i+1)$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n (i+1)=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}+n+1$. Only your leading order term is actually correct.

Comment: I dont know how to calculate sigma functions. Genuinely sorry.
I meant `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` not `for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++)`

Comment: It's still different; you get $\sum_{j=1}^i 1 = i$ and then $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. The method I described shows how to do this.

Comment: Basically your algorithm finds `sigma(i^k, i = 1, i = n) for any k>=1`. How can I put one sigma function inside another sigma function?

Comment: By reducing from the inside out. Say you want to compute $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i 1$, then $\sum_{j=1}^i 1 = i$ and then $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: What if there are 3 sigma functions? Do I have to assume i^k = n(n+1)/2?

Comment: No; you follow the recipe for calculating each sum from the inside out. So if you had $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=1}^j 1$, then that reduces to $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i j$, which reduces to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$. That's the same as $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i + \sum_{i=1}^n i^2}{2}$. Then my algorithm can compute those last two sums.

Comment: By the way, as I pointed out in the other thread, all of the examples we've done so far could also have been computed by calculating the first few values and then computing an appropriate interpolating polynomial. For complicated expressions this is probably easier than using my recursive method. An example: $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=1}^j 1$ should be a polynomial $P(n)$ of degree 3. So you can compute $P(0),\dots,P(3)$ and then fit the data $(0,P(0)),\dots,(3,P(3))$ to a cubic polynomial.