# Methods and knowledge needed for the conversion of $\sum$ and $\prod$ into non-iterative expressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, education, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I think this might be a very broad question, but here it goes.

I have made a formula, using a sigma function, to give the $n$th number in a recursive sequence. I'm trying to make it into a non-iterative formula, but my efforts have only lead to formulas with iterative functions within them. I don't want to post these iterative formulas, and ask for the non-iterative version, because I find I learn best when I figure it out myself. So, instead, I am asking for general methods to do this, and for places where I can get the relevant knowledge for tasks like this.

I've read that Conway and Guy wrote a book, *The Book of Numbers*, with a section dedicated to this subject. However, I'd like to consider some free options before I go ahead and buy this book. After all, it could very well be it is geared towards a higher level of mathematics anyways.

**EDIT:**

Clarification: My current formula, for the $n$th number in a sequence, uses only $n$ as its input. It is a function of $n$. But it has iteration going on. I want to turn my $g(n)$ into $f(n)$, where $f(n)$ has no iterative operations going on.

Example:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k= g(n)$$

This is an iterative function for finding the triangular number of $n$. The higher $n$ is, the greater the computation. I want to snip that computation away with a non-iterative formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \binom{n+1}{2}$$

$$\binom{n+1}{2} = f(n)$$

So, what are some generally applicable methods to make $g(n)$ into $f(n)$? Where can I read about knowledge pertaining to tasks like these?

Comment: Do you want to jump from something like $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ to $a_n=g(n)$?

Comment: @user Nope, I already have a function that only uses the $n-$value. What I want is a jump for $g(n)$ that currently uses a sigma function, into $f(n)$, that uses no iterative functions. My problem is with the iteration.

Comment: It is very hard to guess what the problem really is without seeing any mathematical description. You may at least show one nontrivial example.

Comment: The question is not very clear. But if you are working with polynomials then try giving it to a symbolic engine for factorisation. For  a trivial example: If I want to multiply and sum $a$ and $b$ in all possible orders, iteratively : $aa +ab+ba+bb$, but this factorises to $(a+b)^2$

Comment: @user I have added an example. Not sure if it is nontrivial though? Could you define what would be a trivial and nontrivial example in this situation?

Comment: @SagarM What is a symbolic engine?

Comment: If you're asking about simplifying $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p$ for integer $p$, this is something that's been answered here before; see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194072/where-do-summation-formulas-come-from But this methodology doesn't extend to arbitrary situations.

Comment: @Ian The sum is not of the form $$\sum^n_{k=1} k^p$$, but rather $$\sum^{h(n)}_{k=1} g(n,k)$$. Basically, the $k_{max}$ is a non-iterative function of $n$, and the function iterated over is a function of $n$ and $k$. Hope that made sense. What do you mean by arbitrary situations?

Comment: @user110391 Whether you can do anything analytically depends on what $g$ is. There is no general recipe.

Comment: @Ian I see.  $$g(n,k) = \binom{g_1(n,k)}{k}$$ If I go anymore specific than that then I'd be simply giving the formula I have.

Comment: @user110391 Still doesn't help without knowing what $g_1$ is. It would help if $g_1$ only depended on $n$, though.

Comment: Your notation is confuse. Making $f$ in to $g$ or the converse ?

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> So, what are some generally applicable methods to make g(n) into f(n)?

What you are looking for, if I understand your question correctly, is a
general method for getting a closed form for a finite summation. This is
very analogous to the problem of integration of functions in closed form.
It all depends on the specific summation you have. If you are summing a
polynomial function, the answer depends on Bernoulli numbers (see the
Wikipedia article
[Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)). If you are summing binomial coefficient
terms then [Wilf-Zeilberger pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) is a general method for that.

There are other general methods that are used by Computer Algebra
Systems and I suggest that you can try using them on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the notion of evaluating discrete sums and products. You may achieve this by learning about discrete calculus.

Comment: Do you have any resources for learning about discrete calculus?

Comment: @user110391 I learned it using "A Synopsis of Elementary Results in Pure and Applied Mathematics" and then developed on it on my own deriving much of the identities now understood by commonplace math YouTubers such as Mathologer (who did a video on it recently: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AuV93LOPcE) and Michael Penn (here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNh-Xkfnu1M).

Comment: Those are two very good videos. Basically, if we have an operator satisfying $$\delta f(x)=f(x+\delta x)-f(x)$$ then we have the product rule $$\delta fg=f\delta g+g\delta f+\delta f\cdot \delta g$$ and $\delta^{-1}$ is denoted $\sum$ which corresponds to $$f(x-\delta x)+f(x-2\delta x)+\cdots + C.$$ No need to overcomplicate it. Keep it simple and you'll enjoy your own theories much better.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will check this out.

Answer (score 0):

**A general hint:**

If $f(k)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, then

$$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)=g(n)$$ is a polynomial of degree $d+1$ with the constant term $f(0)$. You can find this polynomial by Lagrangian interpolation on $d+1$ particular values of $n$, or by solving the recurrence

$$g(n)-g(n-1)=f(n).$$ This can be done by the method of indeterminate coefficients. E.g. for the triangular numbers,

$$(an^2+bn)-(a(n-1)^2+b(n-1))=n\iff a=b=\frac12.$$

This method generalizes to polynomials times an exponential, $f(k)a^k$, leading to the recurrence
$$g(n)a^n-g(n-1)a^{n-1}=f(n)a^n$$ or $$g(n)-\frac1ag(n-1)=f(n).$$ The exponential can be complex, allowing additional $\sin$ and $\cos$ factors.

Rational functions $f$ are most of the time difficult and require the use of special functions such as zeta $\zeta$ or polygamma $\psi^{(n)}$, unless telescoping occurs.

---

As a general rule, products are untractable.