# Why is Matt Parker approximation of the average of the highest value of M N-sided dice more and more wrong for higher M?

Tags: statistics, average

In his [video about the unexpected logic behind rolling multiple dice and picking the highest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_DdGRjtwAo), Matt Parker, says that the formula in the end is

$$\frac{m}{m+1}\times n+0.5$$

where $m$ is the number of dice, and $n$ the number of sides on the dice.

I wrote a program that computes the actual values of the averages by simulating all the possible rolls for 20-sided dice (up to 8 dice because it takes too much more time after that). The values I get from my program are also very similar to Matt's values when he simulates the rolls, but those values differ by a greater value at every increase of $m$.

| $m$ | Matt's formula result | Computed result | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.500 | 10.500 | 0 |
| 2 | 13.833 | 13.825 | 0.008 |
| 3 | 15.500 | 15.487 | 0.013 |
| 4 | 16.500 | 16.483 | 0.017 |
| 5 | 17.166 | 17.145 | 0.021 |
| 6 | 17.642 | 17.617 | 0.025 |
| 7 | 18.000 | 17.970 | 0.030 |
| 8 | 18.277 | 18.244 | 0.033 |

Furthermore, if we take much higher values like $m=99$, we get an average of $20.3$, which is absurd because the average is then higher than the maximum rollable value.

So to me, the $+0.5$ part is totally hand-waived and isn't correct from a mathematical point of view.

So where is Matt wrong with the $+0.5$ part, and how to fix his formula so that it's accurate?

Comment: You are looking for the expected value of the maximum here?  But it's easy to compute that exactly.  The probability that the max is $≤i$ is $\left(\frac i{20}\right)^k$ if you have $k$ dice, and you can then get the probability that the max $=i$ by subtraction, so $\left(\frac i{20}\right)^k-\left(\frac {i-1}{20}\right)^k$

Comment: @lulu - the expected value is not so easy for a closed form:  $n - \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i^m}{n^m}$ has a sum of powers related to Bernoulli numbers

Comment: @Henry True, I was just looking at the range of numbers the OP was considering.  I have to imagine the exact computation is easier than the simulation in this range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an expression for the expectation:

- Probability highest is $i$ or less is $\left(\frac in\right)^m$
- Probability highest is exactly $i$ is $\left(\frac in\right)^m-\left(\frac {i-1}n\right)^m$
- Expected value of highest is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\left(\left(\frac in\right)^m-\left(\frac {i-1}n\right)^m\right) = n - \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i^m}{n^m}$

and you will find that this last gives the values you have calculated with $n=20$.

That sum of powers is not in closed form.  For each $m$ it can be expressed as a degree $m+1$ polynomial of $n$ with the terms starting (unchecked) $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i^m=\frac1{m+1}n^{m+1} -\frac12 n^{m}+\frac{m}{12}n^{m-1}-\cdots$.

Plug that into the expected value and you get $n-\frac1{m+1}n +\frac12 -\frac{m}{12} n^{-1}+ \cdots$.  If you keep $m$ fixed and increase $n$, then the terms $-\frac{m}{12} n^{-1}+ \cdots \to 0$ and so you might use $\frac{m}{m+1}n+\frac12$ as an approximation.

While that might be reasonable for large $n$ and small $m$, it is not going to be a reasonable approximation for fixed $n$ and increasing $m$ (i.e. more dice with the same number of sides), as you have noticed.  Putting in one extra term to say $\frac{m}{m+1}n+\frac12-\frac{m}{12} n^{-1}$ works reasonably well for your $n=20$ and $1\le m\le 8$ example (for $m=8$ it gives about $18.4444$ compared to the more exact $18.4445$) but less so for $m=99$ (it gives $19.8875$ compared to the more exact $19.9937$ and you really need more terms).  So this too is not a good approach for large $m$.  Use the full sum of powers instead.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194072/where-do-summation-formulas-come-from might be interesting in this setting. (Also, $E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X>i)$ for a nonnegative integer valued $X$ is a shortcut to your formula...not that your derivation is excessively long or anything.)