# What is the maximum number of intersection of 3d dimention boxes

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics

for example, if I have 2d rectangles the total number of intersections is:
Two rectangles can intersect in at most two points .By looking at all possible pairs of rectangles, the maximum number of intersection is $2\binom{n}{2}=o(2n^2)$.

is it okay to apply this on 3d boxes as well? two boxes can intersect in at most three points, then the maximum number of intersection is $3\binom{n}{3}=o(3n^3)$.

can i apply this also on every dimension? maximum number of intersection of d dimension hyper-rectangles is $d\binom{n}{d}=o(dn^d)$?

I'll try to explain my idea, for intersections circles, I'll get at most pieces $o(n^2)$. for boxes, With all the box intersections, I will then have $o(n^3)$ boxes. is it true? Is this also true for a larger dimension?

for example when 2 circles intersect with each other I get at most 3 pieces, with 3 circles intersecting with each other, I get at most 7 pieces.

[image]

I want to generalize this to 3D and larger dimensions as well.

Comment: No. How do two 3d boxes intersect? If you're looking at the surfaces, they intersect in a closed loop made of straight sections (usually 6), each section being the intersection of two box sides. Furthermore, why would you use $\binom{n}{3}$? You should still be looking at pairwise intersections, not at triplets of boxes. Finally, are you assuming the 2d rectangles are aligned with the axes? If not, two squares or rectangles can intersect in 8 points - just think of two equal size squares with the same centre, one rotated.

Comment: I'll try to explain my idea, for intersections circles, I'll get at most pieces $o(n^2)$. for boxes, With all the box intersections, I will then have $o(n^3)$ boxes. is it true? Is this also true for a larger dimension?

Comment: What do you mean by pieces? What exactly are you counting, both for 2d and for 3d?

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear, for example when 2 circles intersect with each other I get at most 3 pieces, with 3 circles intersecting with each other, I get at most 7 pieces. I want to generalize this to 3D and larger dimensions as well.

Comment: Have a look at [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1145288/362967). For shapes other than circles/spheres, it gets much more complicated.

Comment: sorry, i also forget to mention that is axes-parallel hyper-rectangles, the upper bound for  axes-parallel hyper-rectangles will be $o(n^d)$ , but i might be wrong. it is $o(n^d)$ , because this is the maximum of every  hyper-rectangle intersect with all others